# Send socket result 0x000000be

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, send

What means a result of 0x000000be in send command:

```
iResult = send( ConnectSocket, dataToSend, (int) strlen(dataToSend), 0 );
```

I didn't found this return code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: This should be an answer.

Comment: Thx. In my confusion of finding the return code I overlooked this fact!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value returned by `send` is the number of bytes it sent. If it fails it returns `SOCKET_ERROR` and you use `WSAGetLastError` to get the error code, which is the codes listed in your link. Read the [manual page for `send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Assuming `0x000000be` is being returned by `send()` itself and not `WSAGetLastError()`, then `send()` is not failing at all.  `0x000000be` is 190, which would mean `send()` has successfully sent 190 bytes of data. `0x000000be` is not a valid socket error code that `WSAGetLastError()` can return.